# Password protect part of an DocPad site

Tags: docpad

I guess this may be a 'lost case', but is it possible to password protect one or more pages generated by DocPad?

Is it possible to make a plugin or something that let you say `protected = true` in the metadata section of a page?

Or do I have to use .htaccess or similar to protect my pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're planning to host on a node.js hosting provider, then you can use the following gist: https://gist.github.com/4557006

The idea is that we use the `serverExtend` event to add a new express.js middleware. Middlewares added via the `serverExtend` event are added before docpad's middlewares are added, so this is the ideal place for this authetnication layer as well as most other use cases for custom routes/middlewares etc. Our custom middleware will then check to see if the document that is being requested is a protected document or not, if it isn't it continues down the middleware chain (probably hitting the docpad middlewares and rendering normally) or if it is a protected document then we'll forward it onto the express basicAuth middleware.

Comment: Not thought about hosting yet. Just playing with the idea of using static pages instead of wordpress. Have a little trouble understanding your gist, though. Why is there a docpad middleware? I thought I used DocPad to render the pages once, and then DocPad was out of the game? Do I have to read the docs once more...? ;-)

Comment: @Vegar docpad is more a web framework with static site generation abilities. When running `docpad run` we spin it up with a node.js express.js web server, and the docpad middleware is what tells express how to display our static and dynamic documents. It allows us to do dynamic documents (pages that re-render on each request) and custom routing like we would with other web frameworks. However, if you don't want to do any of that you can just `docpad generate --env static` and deploy your site to apache or github pages or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I had to read some more documentation yesterday :-) Looks like a free heroku hosting would work fine, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yep, sure would. We use free heroku for balupton.com, docpad.org and bevry.me

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could indeed declare `protected = true` in the page metadata and have a collection named protectedPages in `docpad.coffee` :

```
collections:
  protectedPages: (database) ->
    database.findAllLive({protected: true})
```

And then create a file `.htaccess.eco` that looks something like that :

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected area"

<% for document in @getCollection('protectedPages').toJSON(): %>
  <Files "<%= document.url %>">
    Require valid-user
  </Files>

<% end %>
```

and it should be easy to turn this into a plugin that generates the .htaccess file. You could use the [sitemap plugin](https://github.com/benjamind/docpad-plugin-sitemap/blob/master/src/sitemap.plugin.coffee) as an example.

Comment: Awesome solution for static sites. It would be cool to combine this with the node.js solution here - https://gist.github.com/4557006 - into a plugin that handles both use cases. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess we could have an array of objects user/password in the plugin config and generate the .htpasswd file as well.

Answer (score 0):

an other way (but it's just a concept right now) could be :
when you tag a document with a protection (protected:password or need-access-right:account-list) the document is crypted and then published as static content by docpad.

client-side, if you access to a protected page, the crypted content is loaded and a script ask for a password (or for your account info) and then, try to decrypt the content with it.

So you can have protected content on a static server without apache specific .htaccess and it performance issues.